# MySQL: How to use CASE or IF to match on the length of whichever column is shorter?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to match the names columns but some of them contain nicknames for the first names, so I want to do something where I use substring_index to find the first names and whichever table has the shorter first name (e.g. Zach vs Zachary) I match on the length of the shorter first name. After that I match on the last four letters of their last name which I didn't include below. Right now, it's giving me an error near char_length.

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM a, b
WHERE IF (
    a.name < b.name)
    THEN 
    a.name = SUBSTRING(b.name, 1, char_length(a.name))
ELIF (
    b.name < a.name)
THEN
    b.name = SUBSTRING(a.name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(b.name))
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Mandatory link: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Bob, Tom, Dave, Bill, and Sue think your methodology is flawed.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
   CHAR_LENGTH(a.name) < CHAR_LENGTH(b.name)
THEN
  SUBSTR(b.name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(a.name))
ELSE
  SUBSTR(a.name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(b.name))
END
FROM a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Use `LIKE` twice, to find a-names starting with b-names, or b-names starting with a-names.

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM a
JOIN b
  ON a.name like concat(b.name, '%') or b.name like concat(a.name, '%')
```